# Integrating Postman Requests with Unit Testing Framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, frameworks, postman

Say you have developed a number of Postman Requests in a collection. Such requests are huge and complex and they are used to test end-points or perform certain actions such as creating a sample test case for testing be carried out on the web application.

All such requests can, in theory, be scripted using NodeJS, PowerShell, or C#, and within the context of Unit Testing Framework such as Pester, NUnit, Jest, Selenium, Chia, Mocha …etc.

However, we want to take advantage of the work done in Postman and we need to script the invocation of such Postman requests in a given collection, to be executed against a given Environment. All the other details such as Environment Configurations, Authentication, Request Boyd, Request Header …etc. are all configured properly in Postman.

Now I have setup my local dev environment testing project using vscode, C#/PowerShell, Selenium WebDriver and NUnit. I want to script the test case in C# (NUnit) or PowerShell (Pester) to invoke the relevant Postman requests to be executed against the intended environment.

How is this possible?

I appreciate your help.

Tarek

Answer (score 1):

You could use Postman's command line runner `Newman`, and wrap the execution and result evaluation in your code.

See the docs for more details: https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/

Comment: Fantastic! So this means that we have to run the `newman` command line from say C#, this is fine. But, I am still wondering how I will access the results of the post request? For example, I want to get the post status code, and the response data, how?

Comment: Did this once and used the newman-html-reporter-extra (https://npm.io/package/newman-reporter-htmlextra). The generated HTML contains all that data.

Comment: Shouldn't repley from my phone...
I read all that data by parsing the html files of newman-html-reporter-extra

Comment: thanks a lot. It'll be great if you give more info to allow me start the research. How I can parse the html file in C#? Is this the right question to research using google?

Comment: I have no experience in C# at all. I would assume there are libraries to do that.
Google or StackOverflow should provide plenty of answers.
If my answer was helpful, thanks for upvoting and accepting it.

Comment: sure your answer is helpful, however, there is a challenge. How to access the response? If I will use the `Newman` command line from C# or any other language, it's not going to be easy. Parsing HTML is also not fun. I found other options that is using `Newman` NodeJs support and events. There is an event named `response` I think, and this will capture the repsone. Also, I can call NodeJS from C# using Edge.js library.

Comment: `newman run collection.json -r json` will output the result in a json file instead of in the console. So the file can be retrieved from the C# code and parsed.